# How to get the position of connectors on a diagram in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a usecase diagram with an actor and a usecase and there is an association between the two. I want to get the source and target position of the association on the diagram. I tried considering the SX,SY,EX,EY points of the connector in the `PDATA5` column of the `t_connector` table but it doesn't make sense for most of the connectors as they are 0 in most cases.

Is there any other way to get the positions of the connectors on the diagram?

Comment: You have to look at EA.DiagramLink as a connector can appear on more than one diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's complicated. EA renders connectors internally. In your case you have a plain rendering. So what EA does is to find the centers of the two connected elements by looking at the element positions on the diagram (via `t_diagramobjects`). As you might know, EA considers all elements to be rectangular. Use cases and actors the same. This is why connectors do not attach to visible borders but swivel around an invisible frame. Now the geometric centers are calculated and the attachment to those frames (which is simple geometry).

You need to look into `t_diagramlinks` for the connector as well, but only if you shift attachment point or introduce bends. And of course if you have special renderings (like tree style which makes completely different things you can't re-compute (simply)). The `geometry` will tell how shifts are made. And the `path` reveals the bends. Again just simple geometry if you have standard Custom Lines being set. For every other line style: you better don't ask.

Answer (score 0):

From DB side:
t_diagramlinks.geometry (SX,SY)(EX,EY)=(0,0)(0,0) - probably the line from the center of the object to the center. EDGE - where the connector starts (1 top, 2 right, 3 bottom,4 left) from the source object, t_diagramlinks.path - additional break points etc.

Comment: That is definitely where to start, but unfortunately that is not the complete story.